# UID for Trace task commands in arcobjects .net

Tags: arcobjects

I have found below UID for Trace task Dropdown  List.

Trace Task Dropdown List : {DE03EE81-BE26-11D2-BABE-00C04FA33C20}

But nothing is executed when using this UID. I would need to know the exact UID for find connected,find disconnect, find path, Trace downstream and upstream tasks to invoke them from my application developing using arcobjects .net.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ITraceTasks interface to iterate through the names of available tasks. Use the name property of the task to find a match. When you find the task you can get its reference as an ITaskTrace object.

Here is a code example:

```
ITraceTasks traceTasks = (ITraceTasks) ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByName("esriCore.UtilityNetworkAnalysisExt");
string taskName = "Find Common Ancestors";
ITraceTask task;
for (int i = 0; i < traceTasks.TaskCount; i++)
{
    if (traceTasks.Task[i].Name == taskName)
    {
        task = traceTasks.Task[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Esri Documentation here:
[ITraceTasks Documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ITraceTasks.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Are they not simply items of text in a list, there is no UID for them? The UID is for the *control* (Trace Task Dropdown List) which is displaying the *list of values*?

Comment: As metioned above we have executed this UID {DE03EE81-BE26-11D2-BABE-00C04FA33C20} but nothing is happen.

Comment: Have you tried the UID for esriEditorExt.TraceSolver {D6CD856D-BF8F-11D2-BABE-00C04FA33C20}?  From memory it isn't as simple as just executing an ICommandItem to generate a trace, https://github.com/Esri/arcobjects-sdk-community-samples/blob/master/Net/Geodatabase/CustomUpstreamTraceTask/CSharp/CustomUpstreamTraceTaskCSharp.cs might illuminate.